# "I have a pair of Google glass"?

Tags: grammatical-number

How does one state they have a unit of the latest Google Glass glasses, given the way "glasses"  is plural but "Glass" as in Google Glass, is not?

Comment: I have a google Glass. I have two sets of google Glass. A pair of google Glass should be two google Glass

Comment: Someone tweeted "let's make it Google Glass" as in MacBooks Air

Comment: @mplungjan Were you trying to say "**Googles** Glass"?

Comment: @MrLister, Google is not plural.

Comment: FWIW, it's not a pair of anything.  It's a single see-through screen in front of one eye.

Comment: Which is why I said a pair would be TWO of them

Comment: It's amazing how down votes always arrive without explanation...  Glad to see so much positive conversation but why don't the hit-and-run downvoters comment too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say, "I have a Google Glass headset or Google Glass device".

If you had more than one you would say, "I have two Google Glass headsets or devices".

https://developers.google.com/glass/brand-guidelines

> Glass is always capitalized and is never plural or possessive.
>
> Correct: "Send timeline cards to all of your users' Glass", "Get
>   location updates from a user's Glass"
>
> Incorrect: "Wear Google Glasses", "Swipe forward on Glass's timeline"

Comment: There is no way that Google will be able to make everybody talk like this.

Comment: @PeterShor Not yet... but we're working on it...